# Unable to Set flowVars as Key in Json Request

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I am trying to set up the key value for json from the flowVar. Its not working in dataweave 2.0. I might be missing something (syntax). I have a variable test with value. Dataweave code looks like below.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    vars.test: "hi"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [use parenthesis around the key](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-types#dynamic_keys) if it is dynamic:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    (vars.test): "hi"
}
```